# Find parent where all child table values meet requirement

Tags: t-sql

I want to find all incompleted Requests where all related Tasks are completed. Among these Requests find latest completed Task's User email. That is, I need to return RequestID, TaskID, UpdatedDate, email

This is my query:

```
select r.RequestID,r.UpdatedDate,u.Email
from Request r 
left outer join Task t1 on r.RequestID = t1.RequestID
left outer join Task t2 on r.RequestID = t2.RequestID and t2.UpdatedDate > t1.UpdatedDate
left outer join Users u on t1.AssignedEmp = u.UserID
where r.RequestStatusID in (2,6) and t1.TaskStatusID in (2,5)
and t2.RequestID is null
```

This query gives me the latest completed or cancelled task of each Request, but there're other tasks in the same request that is not completed yet. for example these records:

```
RequestID = 1
TaskID = 1, TaskStatusID = 2 (completed) UpdatedDate = '20150417'
TaskID = 2, TaskStatusID = 3 (InProgress)UpdatedDate = '20150416'
```

This request will be selected. But I don't want it. I want all TaskStatusID = Completed or Cancelled

How do I fix it? thanks!

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - I think you got that a bit twisted. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that has `WHERE t2.RequestId is null` will pick up only the rows that didn't find a match in `t2` (or where the column is actually null). The expression `t1.TaskStatusID in (2,5)` does not allow for nulls and will effectively change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `t1` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @habo you are correct. Friday afternoon brain cramp I guess. :-)

Comment: If I understand what you want, there are a couple of approaches. You could either `count` completed tasks `group by RequestId` and compare it to `count` of all tasks `group by RequestId`. If the counts match for a request then all of the tasks are completed. The other approach would be to check each `distinct RequestId` to see if there `exists` an incomplete task and, if so, filter out the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have solved the problem...

```
select r.RequestID, 
t.UpdatedOn, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as UserName, u.Email
from Request r
join
    (

    select RequestID,AssignedEmp, TaskID, Row_Number() OVER (Partition By RequestID Order By UpdatedDate desc) AS RowNo , UpdatedDate, TaskStatusID
    from Task
    where RequestID not in ( select t1.RequestID
                    from Task t1
                    where t1.TaskStatusID not in (2,5)
                    group by t1.RequestID, t1.TaskID
                    )
    ) t                 
on r.RequestID = t.RequestID and t.RowNo = 1
and r.RequestStatusID in (2,6)
join Users u on t.AssignedEmp = u.UserID
order by r.RequestID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a correlated `not exists` subquery to filter out requests with at least one incomplete task. Use apply to get the email for the most recently updated task.

```
select
    r.RequestID,
    r.UpdatedDate,
    u.Email
from Request as r
cross apply (
    select top (1) u.Email
    from Task as t
    inner join Users as u
    on t.AssignedEmp = u.UserID
    where t.RequestID = r.RequestID
    order by r.UpdatedDate desc
) as u /* the user associated with the most recently updated task */
where not exists (
    select *
    from Task as t
    where t.RequestID = r.RequestID
    and t.TaskStatusID <> 2
) /* a not completed task does not exist */
and r.RequestStatusID <> 2 /* the request is not completed */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ranking function (ROW_NUMBER)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) inside a [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.RequestID, t.UpdatedDate DESC) AS Rn
            ,r.RequestID
            ,t.TaskID
            ,r.UpdatedDate
            ,u.Email
    FROM Request AS r
    LEFT JOIN Task AS t ON t.RequestId = r.RequestId
    LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.UserId = t.AssignedEmp
    WHERE r.RequestStatusID IN (2,6)
    AND t.TaskStatusID IN(2, 5)
)
SELECT RequestID, TaskID, UpdatedDate, Email
FROM C
WHERE Rn = 1
```